# XC8 compiler error, 499, when passing a structure

Tags: c, pic, xc8

I have been trying to compile a code. I am very new to XC8 compiler. I have the following code.

**main.c**

```
void main()
{
   bmp280_t bmp280;
   ...
   bmp280.dev_addr = 0x77;
   init_check = bmp280_init(&bmp280);
   ....
}
```

**bmp280.h**

```
...
typedef struct {
    struct bmp280_calib_param_t calib_param;/**<calibration data*/

    uint8_t chip_id;/**< chip id of the sensor*/
    uint8_t dev_addr;/**< device address of the sensor*/

    uint8_t oversamp_temperature;/**< temperature over sampling*/
    uint8_t oversamp_pressure;/**< pressure over sampling*/

    BMP280_WR_FUNC_PTR;/**< bus write function pointer*/
    BMP280_RD_FUNC_PTR;/**< bus read function pointer*/
}bmp280_t;

BMP280_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp280_init(bmp280_t *temp_bmp280);
...
```

**bmp280.c**

```
static bmp280_t *p_bmp280;
BMP280_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE bmp280_init(bmp280_t *temp_bmp280)
{
    /* variable used to return communication result*/
    BMP280_RETURN_FUNCTION_TYPE com_rslt = ERROR;
    uint8_t v_data_u8 = BMP280_INIT_VALUE;

    p_bmp280 = temp_bmp280;/* assign BMP280 ptr */
    /* read chip id */
    com_rslt = p_bmp280->BMP280_BUS_READ_FUNC(p_bmp280->dev_addr,
    BMP280_CHIP_ID_REG, &v_data_u8,
    BMP280_GEN_READ_WRITE_DATA_LENGTH);/* read Chip Id */
    p_bmp280->chip_id = v_data_u8;
    /* readout bmp280 calibparam structure */
    com_rslt += bmp280_get_calib_param();
    return com_rslt;
}
...
```

After executing this code, I am getting an error as

```
":0: error: (499) undefined symbol:
    _bmp280_init(dist/default/production\FTS_basic.X.production.obj) 
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:279: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/FTS_basic.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Abhi/MPLABXProjects/FTS_basic.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:78: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Abhi/MPLABXProjects/FTS_basic.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/FTS_basic.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 10s)
"
```

As I see, there are no typo. The naming is correct. I also hope structure is being passed correctly.

Is there anything new I need to take care in XC8 compiler?

This is for `pic16f1618` microcontroller.

**Makefile-impl.mk**

```
SUB_no=NO
SUBPROJECTS=${SUB_${SUB}}
BUILD_SUBPROJECTS_=.build-subprojects
BUILD_SUBPROJECTS_NO=
BUILD_SUBPROJECTS=${BUILD_SUBPROJECTS_${SUBPROJECTS}}
CLEAN_SUBPROJECTS_=.clean-subprojects
CLEAN_SUBPROJECTS_NO=
CLEAN_SUBPROJECTS=${CLEAN_SUBPROJECTS_${SUBPROJECTS}}


# Project Name
PROJECTNAME=FTS_basic.X

# Active Configuration
DEFAULTCONF=default
CONF=${DEFAULTCONF}

# All Configurations
ALLCONFS=default 


# build
.build-impl: .build-pre
    ${MAKE} -f nbproject/Makefile-${CONF}.mk SUBPROJECTS=${SUBPROJECTS} .build-conf


# clean
.clean-impl: .clean-pre
    ${MAKE} -f nbproject/Makefile-${CONF}.mk SUBPROJECTS=${SUBPROJECTS} .clean-conf

# clobber
.clobber-impl: .clobber-pre .depcheck-impl
        ${MAKE} SUBPROJECTS=${SUBPROJECTS} CONF=default clean



# all
.all-impl: .all-pre .depcheck-impl
        ${MAKE} SUBPROJECTS=${SUBPROJECTS} CONF=default build



# dependency checking support
.depcheck-impl:
#   @echo "# This code depends on make tool being used" >.dep.inc
#   @if [ -n "${MAKE_VERSION}" ]; then \
#       echo "DEPFILES=\$$(wildcard \$$(addsuffix .d, \$${OBJECTFILES}))" >>.dep.inc; \
#       echo "ifneq (\$${DEPFILES},)" >>.dep.inc; \
#       echo "include \$${DEPFILES}" >>.dep.inc; \
#       echo "endif" >>.dep.inc; \
#   else \
#       echo ".KEEP_STATE:" >>.dep.inc; \
#       echo ".KEEP_STATE_FILE:.make.state.\$${CONF}" >>.dep.inc; \
#   fi
```

Comment: It seems to be a linking problem. Doyou have the `_bmp280_init` symbol anywhere in your code?

Comment: Is `bmp280.c` compiled and linked? Is `bmp280.h` included into `main.c`?

Comment: Hi, I figured out that it is linking error through the xc8 compiler document. But I could not figure out, how. I have used the init function in main and I have defined it in the corresponding header file. If I remove the parameters, that is the structure reference, the build passes.

Comment: Yes the header file is included.

Comment: Sorry!! Just compiled again by removing the parameter, even then the build crashes. So, its not with respect to the parameter.

Comment: Is `bmp280.c` compiled and linked?

Comment: Should it be compiled separately? wouldn't the build take care of everything?

Comment: It cannot if you don't specify files to be linked. Could you post the xc8 command? BTW some IDE, like mplab, manage to compile and link all files added to a project.

Comment: I have been using MPLAB X IDE V3.26. And I do not use any other command. I directly click on build.

Comment: I am observing one more behavior. When I try to right click and click on compile certain files like main.c, or mcc_generated_files, the IDE compiles. But when I try to do the same for the files I have added externally, I am not able to compile. There is no action at all. It is like I never clicked on compile.

Comment: Hi.. Can anyone please help me out? I am still not able to figure it out. @LPs

Comment: Try to remove a source file from project and then re-add it. This action should force mplab to rebuild the makefile. If the problem persists could you post the makefile content?

Comment: @LPs I tried removing and adding it again. It did not help. I have re-edited the post with the Makefile. Should I add anything in the build-pre section?

Comment: Probably we need `Makefile-impl.mk` contents. Post it instead of the one posted now.

Comment: @LPs I tried building with SUB_no=YES as well. I have edited my post with Makefile-impl.mk

Comment: @LPs I Have edited even the error log. If it helps.

Comment: Are all source files into same directory?

Comment: @LPs No, they are not. Two files, main.c and another one are out of all the directories. bmp280 files are inside a folder named bmp280 and few files in another directory, and mcc_generated_files in their respective directory.

Comment: Try to put all files in a dir and create a fresh new project. I still thinking your IDE is not compiling the bmp280.c file...

Comment: @LPs I will try that. I had also tried to compile each file, by right clicking on the file and selecting compile. It compiled main.c and few other mcc_generated_files, but did not compile bmp280.c

Comment: @LPs I am able to compile it now. There are few other errors and I can solve them. Thank you for your help and time! :) The file structure was the main problem. Thanks a lot :)